# SDC constraint inside Xilinx ISE

Tags: fpga, xilinx, ise, constraints

Inside ISE timing constraint editor window, which following sub-section shall I use *set_clock_group* to solve the STA setup timing violation path #1 due to [cross-clock signal](https://github.com/promach/DDR/blob/main/ddr3_memory_controller.v#L1514-L1528) ?

[image: timing_constraint_editor]

[image: violation_path]

Comment: I think you should ask tool specific questions in Xilinx Forum. But since this is ISE which is too old, I doubt if you get any support at all.

Answer (score 1):

Two comments.

1. It may be time to consider upgrading to Vivado. ISE is nearing its end of life for the Xilinx FPGA families
2. When you have a defined clock boundary crossing a common way to flag that in SDC is to use the `set_false_path` constraint between the two domains. You would only do this if you knew that the crossing was dealt with properly, such as with a FIFO.

Since you're working with a DDR controller, the assumption is that:

- Inputs use a FIFO re-timed using a DLL with incoming DQS signal
- Outputs a FIFO and per-lane clock phasing to compensate DDR fly-by timing

In either case, each lane set is its own clock domain, distinct from the reference clock.

Comment: Synchronizing Fast Signals Into Slow Clock Domain might be the more difficult case as described in https://www.verilogpro.com/clock-domain-crossing-part-1/.  I do not understand what you meant **re-timed using a DLL** as well as **clock phasing** ?

Comment: DDR3 supports variable DQ/DQS timing that allows the clock/control group to be routed using a ‘fly-by’ topology. The controller compensates the timing for each lane.

Comment: I am still confused as in how does **DLL** fits into the picture in this case ?

Comment: The read DQS signal is phase-aligned with DQ. To sample the DQ properly, the host must make a 90-degree phase shifted clock. The DLL references DQS and makes this phase-shifted clock.